# Cocos2d 0.8.2 (from 0.7.2)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am switching from cocos2d 0.7.2 to 0.8.2 for cocosdenshion, but now i get 7 errors!

```
Undefined symbols:
"_OBJC_IVAR_$_TransitionScene.inSceneOnTop", referenced from:
_OBJC_IVAR_$_TransitionScene.inSceneOnTop$non_lazy_ptr in PageTurnTransition.o
"_inflateEnd", referenced from:
_inflateMemory_ in ZipUtils.o
_inflateMemory_ in ZipUtils.o
_inflateMemory_ in ZipUtils.o
"_OBJC_IVAR_$_CocosNode.anchorPoint_", referenced from:
_OBJC_IVAR_$_CocosNode.anchorPoint_$non_lazy_ptr in BitmapFontAtlas.o
"_inflate", referenced from:
_inflateMemory_ in ZipUtils.o
"_OBJC_IVAR_$_CocosNode.position_", referenced from:
_OBJC_IVAR_$_CocosNode.position_$non_lazy_ptr in ParallaxNode.o
"_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
_inflateMemory_ in ZipUtils.o
"_OBJC_IVAR_$_CocosNode.contentSize_", referenced from:
_OBJC_IVAR_$_CocosNode.contentSize_$non_lazy_ptr in BitmapFontAtlas.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you haven't included the proper headers or linked the proper modules.

Comment: well its from cocos2d 0.8.2 so i didnt write any of them